# What is the best way to compute a similarity matrix for a dataframe of binary vectors?

Tags: python, binary, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have an data frame of size m x n of binary vectors with some unfilled values like the below sample

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 V0    1         0    1
 V1    1    1         0
 V2    0    1    0    1
 V3         0    0
```

I would like to compute a similarity matrix on this data frame such that I get a similarity score between any 2 vectors.

What is the best way to do this?

Note: I attempted replacing the NULL values with 2 and applied cosine similarity from the scipy library on the dataframe. The result matrix was not accurate/correct.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [pdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist) or [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) with binary distance functions such as dice, jaccard or hamming (see [the list of these functions at the end of this page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html)).